# Linear subspaces of quadric surface over arbitrary fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, quadrics

I was wondering if there already exists some text that present classical results on quadrics in a modern language. Ideally using the language of schemes, however the setting of varieties over arbitrary fields $k$ including characteristic 2 would already be sufficient to me.

Examples of the kind of statements that I am looking for are basically treated in chapter 22 of Harris his algebraic Geometry book, especially Theorem 22.14 from that book.

To be more concrete:

Let $k,n$ with $k<n$ be integers, $S$ be a scheme and $Q \subseteq \mathbb P^n_S$ be a smooth quadric hypersurface. Then one can define $F_{k}(Q) \subset \mathbb G_S(k,n)$ to be the the closed subscheme of the Grassmannian parameterizing $k$ dimensional projective subspaces inside $Q$.

Suppose $n=2k+1$, then there exists an etale dubble cover $T \to S$ such that $F_{k}(Q)_T = F_{k,1}(Q) \cup F_{k,2}(Q)$ is the disjoint union of two $T$ schemes $F_{k,1}(Q)$ and $F_{k,2}(Q)$. And furthermore all geometric fibers of $F_{k,1}(Q)$ and $F_{k,2}(Q)$ are reduced and irreducible.

If 2 is invertible in $S$ then the etale double cover $T \to S$ can basically be obtained by taking the square root of the discriminant of $Q$.